# How can I extract the value between 2 signs?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following website format:

https://smth.something.com/word/?1746636d-450c-4e3b-bec6-f9c8749f6644&sh_

How can I extract the value between "?" and "&", to receive the code "1746636d-450c-4e3b-bec6-f9c8749f6644"?

I'm trying to use RegEx `(?<=?)(.*)(?=&)` but the following mistake appears: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?`

Comment: You have to escape the questionmark. Try `(?<=\?).*?(?=&)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative look behind won't work in general in JavaScript (currently supported in Chrome only) as its not yet widely supported and you need to escape `?` as `\?` as `?` is a special character in regex.

You can use this regex,

```
\?([^&]+)
```

And get your data from group1

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M5p7qW/1/)**

JS demo,

```js
const s = 'https://smth.something.com/word/?1746636d-450c-4e3b-bec6-f9c8749f6644&sh_'
console.log(s.match(/\?([^&]+)/)[1])
```

Comment: I received the following mistake:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: You need to also escape `?` as `\?`